# What is the Windows 7 command-line to remove all remember passwords in Credential Manager?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, security, passwords, credentials-manager

We can remove remembered/cached passwords via Credential Manager as [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile) and via a command `cmdkey` as [here](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2008/12/managing-stored-credentials-from-the-windows-command-prompt-using-cmdkey.htm).

I want to have one command that quickly clear all the passwords. How can we do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for that, you sure need to create a batch file. maybe follwing link will help you on this

This is the [similar post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f7824d63-0aab-4364-80e3-a3ac4c52e5cd/need-a-script-for-delete-all-credentials-using-cmdkey?forum=w7itpronetworking). Try it out.

The script

```
cmdkey.exe /list > "%TEMP%\List.txt"
findstr.exe Target "%TEMP%\List.txt" > "%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%G IN (%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt) DO cmdkey.exe /delete:%%H
del "%TEMP%\List.txt" /s /f /q
del "%TEMP%\tokensonly.txt" /s /f /q
```

Comment: When I run this as administrator, I get: `Hdel was unexpected at this time` - what does that mean?

Answer (score 11):

Try the following one-liner:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do  cmdkey /delete %H
```

It does exactly what the batch file does, but without the temporary files, and in a single line. Pipe the results of the cmdkey /list into findstr (which will search for a string from STDIN). Then use the result inside of a FOR loop using it's single quote "command to process" feature, and, deleting each of the items (the second parameter in the list) A nifty way to do the same thing as the batch file using just standard piping, and no temporary files.

Comment: Can you explain what this command does? It has been flagged for removal as it lacks context. Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: It does exactly what the batch file does, but without the temporary files, and in a single line.  
Pipe the results of the cmdkey /list into findstr (which will search for a string from STDIN).
Then use the result inside of a FOR loop using it's single quote "command to process" feature, and, deleting each of the items (the second parameter in the list)
A nifty way to do the same thing as the batch file using just standard piping, and no temporary files.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that information...

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Worked great. Note FINDSTR is cAsE sEnSiTivE by default. Example Outlook flush usage: ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr /i office') but note it would also match a logon like 'securityofficer@org' so you may want to be more specific.

Comment: What syntax can we use to search for and delete strings with a space like "my office"? Does this command search everywhere in the returned text, like the 'target', the 'username' and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but it depends on how many 'targetnames' you have.

```
cmdkey /delete:Administrator && cmdkey /delete:Knuckle-Dragger
```

Comment: As in my OP, I want to delete all.